# RFID scanner- HZ 1050 Module

Tags: rfid

I just bought a rfid scanner hz 1050 module at $5 to add to my project,in the module I see a lot of pins to male my connections.
Am getting stuck on the ones to use for arduino.
I will be glad to anyone who helps me out.Thank you.

Comment: Link: Quick web-search gave a link to Nick Gammon's excellent blog. Start here: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=316450.0

Comment: You haven't even told us what the pins are or what connection type the scanner is ... serial? I2C? SPI? something else?

Comment: The pins are the 5V GND,D1,DO,TXD..Am getting troubled in the  the last three pins. The module is to be connected to arduino and LCD 12c..